Is it possible to make a drawing app that allows only drawing certain shapes and alphabets like below image in Flutter?
I want to create a drawing application for kids that allows them draw alphabets and certain shapes like Circle, rectangle, square .... but not let them draw freely but let them draw between certain points like the image below.
[Duolingo ABC line drawing example] (https://i.sstatic.net/rU6TptMk.png)
As you can see in the image, instead of free drawing you should drag a handle and draw the shape that you need to. You can also use this with English alphabets.
I have tried using a custom painter and some drawing packages, they're all good for drawing freely on screen but not for drawing a complete letter like 'A'.
I have also tried creating a line using a container so that you are forced to draw within the container but it has 2 problems. First I couldn't firgure out how to create the handle like in the pic and secondly it's impossible to define complex shapes like alphabets and multipart shapes like a rectangle.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
